# MPMoviePlayerViewController frame size

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this method:

```
-(void) playMov: (NSString*) title{
 //   play a movie!!
NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:@"mp4"];
self.mpviewController =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];

[self.mpviewController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 275)];

self.mpviewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.mpviewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];


 MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
mp.contentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath];
 CGRect playerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 275);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mp];

 [mp.view setFrame:playerFrame];
 mp.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [mp prepareToPlay];
 [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];  
}
```

The first time the view is loaded - it's full screen with black background.
After the first time is on the wanted size (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 275) still black background.
I want it to be this size and clear background color  every time.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `backgroundView` property of the `MPMoviePlayerController` class.

Comment: UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backimage];

    [[mp backgroundView] addSubview:imgView];

worked :)